# Conky Tomorrow Setup

Tags: conky

I've had Conky Tomorrow since January, and the temperatures were shown properly. But as you know Yahoo's Weather API isn't free longer (the forecast wasn't show any more), so I got a (free) key in http://openweathermap.org/. I have all the weather forecast in my city, but the problem is that I'm unable to change the commands to adapt the old Conky script to a new one which shows the forecast.

As I can see, the comands I have to change are:

```
 ${execi 300 curl -s "CODE OF THE FORECAST IN MY CITY" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}
 ${font Raleway:size=20}${voffset -40}
 ${goto 16}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}°${font Raleway:weight=Light:size=14}${goto 114}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°${goto 224}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°${goto 334}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==4'}°${goto 444}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==5'}°

  ${font Raleway:weight=Light:size=10}${goto 150}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°${goto 260}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°${goto 370}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==4'}°${goto 480}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==5'}°
```

And the information (in xml, but it also can be show in json) that I got is

```
 <forecast>
 <time from="2016-04-16T12:00:00" to="2016-04-16T15:00:00">
 <symbol number="500" name="light rain" var="10d"/>
 <precipitation unit="3h" value="0.11" type="rain"/>
 <windDirection deg="245.51" code="WSW" name="West-southwest"/>
 <windSpeed mps="7.71" name="Moderate breeze"/>
 <temperature unit="celsius" value="16.44" min="16.44" max="16.44"/>
 <pressure unit="hPa" value="990.11"/>
 <humidity value="83" unit="%"/>
 <clouds value="scattered clouds" all="44" unit="%"/>
 </time>
 <time from="2016-04-16T15:00:00" to="2016-04-16T18:00:00">
 <symbol number="802" name="scattered clouds" var="03d"/>
 <precipitation/>
 <windDirection deg="248.5" code="WSW" name="West-southwest"/>
 <windSpeed mps="6.46" name="Moderate breeze"/>
 <temperature unit="celsius" value="14.31" min="14.3" max="14.31"/>
 <pressure unit="hPa" value="990.94"/>
 <humidity value="78" unit="%"/>
 <clouds value="scattered clouds" all="32" unit="%"/>
 </time>
```

So, anybody knows how to change the Conky comands?

It would be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From oct 2015 you must use a url curl command like :

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=YOURCITY&APPID={APIKEY}&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=5&lang=xx
```

Where:

- `xx` is your language: en, es, etcetera.
- The `ApiKey` can be obteined signing up.
- The `YOURCITY` variable is the name of your city. It's better to use your CityID.

More info about API at : [OpenWeather](http://www.openweathermap.org/api)

Finally,  you must change all the variables names obteined with curl to read all the weather conditions.

List of all variables can see at [API Openweather XML output](http://www.openweathermap.org/current#current_XML)

You can see an example at: [Conky Gnow](http://www.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Gnow-multilang-505074617).  Click on ***Download*** link, unzip the file and take a look into `.conkyrc` file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The point is that I've got the key and the forecast in my city in JSON and XLM. My problem is that I don't know who to change the Conky conf in order to real the xml/json file properly. The one I showed worked with the Yahoo API.

Comment: @Minkowski you must change all the variables names. I've edited my answer to add an example.

Comment: "change all variables names": where are they? where is the provided example? please, add more details

Comment: @cipricus I edited the answer to more information.

Comment: for reference: a similar conky ([Visions](http://zagortenay333.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Vision-395777503)) was updated to fit the change to OpenWeather.

Answer (score -1):

I finally got Conky Harmattan. Its author has adapted to OpenWeatherMap. It works perfectly.

Comment: You didn't say how you got it, which would be useful to future visitors.

Comment: Let's see. I finally wasn't able to fix my conky file. I just downloaded Conky Harmattan from http://zagortenay333.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Harmattan-426662366 and followed the steps. But I repeat, I didn't achieve my target.